Missing `Retry-After` in reponse header in Spotify API
I'm using Python requests to get some info from Spotify API, After some requests, I encountered the 429 error, which indicates that the request limit has been exceeded. It is written in the Spotify document that when you encounter this error, there is a Retry-After in the response header that you have to wait for that amount of time and request again, but the response header that I receive does not have such a thing.
Here is the code:
url = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/{track_id}'
res = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
if res.ok:
    return res.json()
if res.status_code == 429:
    print("------------- 429 ----------------")
    print(res.headers)
    return None

Here is the response header:
{
   "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   "cache-control": "private, max-age=0",
   "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
   "access-control-allow-headers": "Accept, App-Platform, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin, Retry-After, Spotify-App-Version, X-Cloud-Trace-Context, client-token, content-access-token",
   "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH",
   "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
   "access-control-max-age": "604800",
   "content-encoding": "gzip",
   "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000",
   "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
   "date": "Mon, 22 Jul 2024 11:51:11 GMT",
   "server": "envoy",
   "Via": "HTTP/2 edgeproxy, 1.1 google",
   "Alt-Svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000",
   "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked"
}


The Spotify docs say that it normally includes a RETRY_AFTER header. However, sometimes, it is not included. You may need to make a "best guess" estimate. Python's HTTPAdapter provides a simple way to configure a retry strategy using sessions.

bumping your question by delete/repost is a bad strategy: you can be banned from asking questions, and deleted questions still count

You may need to experiment since you don't know how long to wait, and there is no RETRY_AFTER in the response header. Pass a retry object for fine-grained control over different types of retries.
Starting with a backoff_factor=2, this retry object is configured to handle three retries with a progressively longer delay, having a delay of 2, 4, 8... seconds before failing.
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

retry_strategy = Retry(
    total=3,
    backoff_factor=2
)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
http = requests.Session()
http.mount("https://", adapter)
http.mount("http://", adapter)

url = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/{track_id}'
res = http.get(url, headers=self.headers)

In my example, the retry_strategy is for a total of three retries with progressively longer delays 2, 4, 8... seconds before failing.

Thanks for your response, But I saw somewhere that the token was banned for more than 1 day, I will test your code

@SaeedHosseini It can get banned quickly if you do not configure a backoff before the token gets banned. Try a high number, i.e., start with 60 as the backoff factor and work your way down to the lowest acceptable number.
